# Angular 9 go to anchor on different page

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular9

I want to have a link that goes to a page and a certain section, in plain HTML I would just use `<a href="myPage#mySection">go to my section</a>` and I would be able to use it everywhere.

How should I do this in Angular 9? When searching for this I find a lot of old answers that don't work anymore. I am sorry if this seems like a simple question but I am still getting used to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `RouterLink` (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink), you can use the `fragment` input to pass the anchor:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['myPage']" fragment="mySection">
  link
</a>
```

You will also have to enable `anchorScrolling` in your router configuration:
https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling

Comment: I tried using the fragment before but this gave errors, but that was because I didn't enable anchorScrolling.

Comment: i gave complete stackblitz for same below.

Answer (score 1):

Please go on url below and vote solution if it works:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6bcr7

Inside stackblitz browser, try https://angular-m6bcr7.stackblitz.io/home#myFirst